# Select query to return records where column A has one to many relationship column B - ORA-00937 error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to write a query that returns all records where a value the first column maps to more than one distinct values in the second column. I tried the following but got a 'not a single-group group function'. What am I doing wrong here?

```
select contact_id, count(location_account_id)
from
(select a.contact_id, a.location_account_id
from crm.asset_plus a 
where a.contact_id is not null
group by a.contact_id, a.location_account_id)
having count(location_account_id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the HAVING clause to the sub-query and include the count also in the sub-query SELECT.

```
Select  SQ.contact_id
from    (
        select  a.contact_id
                ,count(a.location_account_id)
        from    crm.asset_plus a 
        where   a.contact_id is not null
        group by 
                a.contact_id
        having  count(a.location_account_id) > 1
        ) SQ
```

If you need to include the count in your final output - then just use the sub-query be itself.

Based on the comments below, here is a revised query, that counts the `DISTICT` values of the locatin_account_id

```
Select  SQ.contact_id
from    (
        select  a.contact_id
                ,count(distinct a.location_account_id)
        from    crm.asset_plus a 
        where   a.contact_id is not null
        group by 
                a.contact_id
        having  count(distinct a.location_account_id) > 1
        ) SQ
```

Comment: Sorry I need to find records where each contact_id is linked to more than one distinct location_account_id.

Comment: OK, that is what this query does.

Comment: It doesn't, I tried the same query before I posted the question. It pulls in instances where there are say 2 records for the same contact_id value and and the same location_account_id value (as well as the records I need). I need only instances where there are 2+ records that have the same contact_id value but different, distinct values for the location_account_id.

Comment: I have added a new query that looks for the count of distinct values for the location_account_id.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your trying to do?

```
SELECT contact_id, location_account_id
FROM crm.asset_plus a 
JOIN (
    SELECT contact_id, location_account_id
    FROM crm.asset_plus 
    WHERE a.contact_id is not null
    GROUP BY contact_id
    HAVING count(1) > 1
) X ON X.asset_plus  = A.asset_plus  AND X.location_account_id = A.location_account_id
```